# Covariance of uniform random and indicator function dependant on it

Tags: uniform-distribution, covariance

Define $I = \begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } X\leq a\\
    0,& \text{if } X\gt a
\end{cases}$

$X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. We want to compute $Cov(I,X)$ which involves $E[IX]$.

$E[IX] = E[IX|I=1]P(I=1)+E[IX|I=0]P(I=0)=E[X]P(I=1)=E[X]P(X\leq a)=E[X]E[I]$

Hence, $Cov(I,X) = 0$.

This is wrong since they are not independent but I'm not sure where is the mistake.

Is it that $E[IX|I=1] \neq E[X] = \frac{1}{2}$, instead $E[IX|I=1] = \frac{a}{2}$?

Comment: Note that $E[IX|I=1] = E[X|I=1] \neq E[X]$.  Indeed, given that $I=1$, you would expect the value of $X$ to be less than it would be without this info.